# Adding a symbol to a certain index of an integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My goal is to have a function that will generate a random 12 digit number and then display this number back to the user using an alert with a particular format.

My end result would display a integer with a number format like this

```
1234-5678-4321
```

Currently all I have is the random number generator function which you can see below. I don't think this is the best way to generate a 12 digit number but it seems to work.

```
function ticketGenerator() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 899999999999) + 100000000000);
}
```

What I cannot figure out how to do, is to add the `"-"` symbol for every 4th number in the index of the integer.  I would like to save this variable as an Integer to the database, so I am trying to avoid parsing this Integer to a String but don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Does this value have to be unique?

Comment: checkout formatter.js its a great library for what you want to do
http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/demos.html

Comment: are leading zeros valid ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generate 3 * 4 nums and join them with an - :

```
function random(){
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 ** 4);
}

function ticketGenerator(){
  return Array.from({length:3},random).join("-");
}
```

Or if you really want to modify a 12 digit string:

```
function format(number){
  return number.toString().split("").map(
    (char,i) => (!i || i%4?"":"-")+char
  ).join("");
}

format(123456789101) //"1234-5678-9101"
```

Answer (score 0):

By way of another option, you can use a simple regex to insert a dash every fourth character.

```js
var r = /(.{4})(?=.)/g;
var numberString = '' + ticketGenerator();

var result = numberString.replace(r, '$1-');
```

I'm not saying it's better or worse than the options already provided... it's just another one. If you don't understand or hate regex, this one probably isn't for you.

```js
function ticketGenerator() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 899999999999) + 100000000000);
}

var r = /(.{4})(?=.)/g;
var numberString = '' + ticketGenerator();

var result = numberString.replace(r, '$1-');

console.log(result);
```